# Custom views not loading in production mode, but load in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, spree, unicorn

I'm creating a completely new frontend for spree (need a custom set of markup and JS, so Deface isn't a good option in this case).

The views I override work fine in development but once I load it up in production it starts to load the views from the core and frontend gems

All my overrides are located in

app/views/spree/...

But that is all ignored in production and is loaded from the default gems.

I'm running Unicorn and Nginx on top.

Anyone have the slightest idea what could be the case?

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'thin', '~> 1.5.1'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'unicorn', '~> 3.6.2', :require => nil

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.1'
  gem 'haml', '4.0.2'
  gem 'haml-rails', '0.4'
  gem 'swf_fu', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'spree', '2.0.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_static_content', :github => 'spree/spree_static_content', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

Log file:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 14:10:58 +0400
Processing by Spree::HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_taxonomies.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_products.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb within spree/layouts/spree_application (16.8ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_core-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_routes.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered spree/shared/_head.html.erb (11.9ms)
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/shared/_nav_bar'
Deface: 'auth_shared_login_bar' matched 1 times with 'li#search-bar'
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_search.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_nav_bar.html.erb (10.2ms)
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/shared/_main_nav_bar'
Deface: 'pages_in_header' matched 1 times with '#main-nav-bar'
Deface: [WARNING] No :original defined for 'pages_in_header', you should change its definition to include:
 :original => 'db2835f20e2ab66e854a74f6ae2a05cfb86f20fd' 
  Rendered spree/static_content/_static_content_list.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb (6.6ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_header.html.erb (33.4ms)
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/shared/_sidebar'
Deface: 'pages_in_sidebar' matched 1 times with '#sidebar'
Deface: [WARNING] No :original defined for 'pages_in_sidebar', you should change its definition to include:
 :original => 'd1fc4156cbab1ac52f706094ef49c096c6cc99c6' 
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_sidebar.html.erb (3.2ms)
Deface: 1 overrides found for 'spree/shared/_footer'
Deface: 'pages_in_footer' matched 1 times with '#footer-right'
Deface: [WARNING] No :original defined for 'pages_in_footer', you should change its definition to include:
 :original => '0e70b64f6d6eb3161e2de39b8253df9c0a201c63' 
  Rendered spree/static_content/_static_content_list.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_footer.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/gems/spree_frontend-2.0.3/app/views/spree/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 117.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
Started GET "/assets/store/all-ca3b1f4927eae975c1f7c79787f2ca94.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 14:10:58 +0400
Served asset /store/all-ca3b1f4927eae975c1f7c79787f2ca94.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Started GET "/assets/store/all-f0bc96963b93c18206d8e0486f8ea783.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 14:10:58 +0400
Served asset /store/all-f0bc96963b93c18206d8e0486f8ea783.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Started GET "/assets/admin/bg/spree_50-ba6539ca1486ea7b446a777fa2d422ef.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 14:10:58 +0400
Served asset /admin/bg/spree_50-ba6539ca1486ea7b446a777fa2d422ef.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Started GET "/assets/admin/bg/spree_50-ba6539ca1486ea7b446a777fa2d422ef.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 14:12:06 +0400
Served asset /admin/bg/spree_50-ba6539ca1486ea7b446a777fa2d422ef.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

Comment: you should look the differences between config/environments/development.rb and config/environments/production.rb. Maybe you have a load path that is configured in one and not another ; push it up to config/application.rb

Comment: Between these files almost no differences. There is not used any load paths. I start rails in prod mode on my local computer, but the problem remained.

Comment: Maybe that's your issue? https://github.com/spree/deface/issues/102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. My Spree version is 2.0 stable, аnd it uses Deface gem, which not working with HAML templates. 
I just moved back to the ERB. New versions of Spree probably already have to support Haml.

Thank you all.